# On Premise Ruby on Rails Application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, server

I would like to ask you a question about deploying a rails application onto a physical server.

Briefly, our dinosaur client doesn't want to store anything on the cloud hence he wants us to deploy everything onto his servers instead of heroku.

What should be the most efficient way to solve this problem? Won't he be able to reach the source code of our application?

That would be great if you can help me,

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You might think on the variant when you keep only production database (and assets if client want) on the client's server and deploy your code to Heroku or whatever else.

Comment: yes, that's why we offered however they also want to store the source code on their own servers